# How to bundle a folder which is outside in project folder

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We are having multiple .NET MVC projects linked each other but some script and css files are same for all.
Folder structure is as below

```
- Root folder
    - Assets
        - Js
        - CSS
    - Project 1
    - Project 2
    - Project 3
```

All common js and are inside Assets/js and Assers/Css folder which is lying outside project folders.
Can we bundle Assets folder into Project 1,2 and 3?

Thank you for any hint/guidance in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You just need to add some codes in tjhe `App_Start\BundleConfig.cs` file of each project.

Like this, you add in the method `RegisterBundles`:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("Root/Assets/js").Include(
             "Root/Assets/Js/*.js")); //You put your path where there is the Root

 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("Root/Assets/css").Include(
             "Root/Assets/CSS/*.css")); //You put your path where there is the Root



     // Code removed for clarity.
}
```

And then you you can put these lines inside each `Layout.cshtml`

```
@Styles.Render("Root/Assets/css")
@Scripts.Render("Root/Assets/js")
```

To call your `Js` library and `CSS` files.

I hope it will help

Comment: It is not working when is set BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, create a web setup project...

```
New Project > Other Project Types > Setup and Deployment > Visual Studio Installer > Web Setup Project
```

Then right mouse click on the setup project and select

```
View > File System
```

From there you can add custom folders / files that will be included in the setup file that is deployable.

Comment: This is a MVC web application, this doesn't need any installation. It is hosted on IIS.

Comment: @VivekDeshmukh All the installer does is copy everything the app needs to the relevent IIS directory... MVC apps still get compiled, everything but the views I believe, so models, controllers and any other code / .cs files... so an installation is still valid.